# R Session Aborted while loading RWeka

Tags: r, rstudio, rweka

I cannot load RWeka library in Rstudio session while I have got it installed without problems.

The library(RWeka) command is simply interrupted by a "R Session Aborted" error and R is restarted.

I'm currently working with

- Windows 10
- RStudio 2022.02.2 Build 485
- R 4.2.0

I have tried to load RWeka running R in a terminal and I haven't had any problem.
Any suggestion will be wellcome.
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I've confirmed it on Twitter. I have now found a solution: you need to install a patched version of R, available here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html. Take care to select the patched version in RStudio and then the crash should disappear.

Comment: Can you add the version number which you used when you posted it last year?